Connecting multiple pins of multiple connectors together on 2-layer PCB
In my case, I need to connect all pins of J1, J2, J3 except pin 4 together. The connectors are not below, but next to each other. Currently I use a 2-layer PCB.
While in the schematics this is simple, on the PCB I would need multiple layers because the tracks otherwise would block each other.
What is the best practise for such a purpose? While I am open for 4 instead of 2 layers, I want to learn how this usually is resolved on 2 layers.



Can you define how many layers you have? Just one?

Depends on the speed of the signals, their currents, etc.

It is a 2-layer PCB, I updated the question.

If you rotate the connectors by 90°, would that make it easier?

It would make the tracing indeed easier, but not really the rest of the design.

How much current do you want to run through those traces?

Couple of options spring to mind. Really it depends on how many traces and connections you have.
For a small number of 1-to-1 mapped connections, you can route the connector-to-connector traces on a single layer without any vias, then the non-common signals can be routed on the other layer. This is essentially as if the connectors were 90 degree oriented and you just routed through, but then spun the connectors around to their final position. Essentially forming a sort of zig-zag under the connectors:

For bigger buses (and small ones too), you can use horizontal-vertical routing paradigm. Whereby you run horizontal traces on one layer as a large bus, then using via taps on these bus lines, run vertical traces to the connectors on the other layer.


The horizontal-vertical routing paradigm was at the end the best solution :)

If you were to turn the middle connector 180°, you could easily connect all three on a single plane. Downside is of course having the locking tabs the other way around to the rest of the connectors.

